# How to efficiently check the first list that have the concept in python

Tags: python

I have 5 lists as follows.

```
list1 = [[111, ["food", "fruits", "vegetables"]], [112, ["mango", "apples", "grapes", "pears", "passion fruit"]]]
list2 = [[110, ["transport", "car", "van", "bus", "jeep"]], [109, ["trams", "trains", "passenger", "driver"]], [108, ["traffic", "lights"]]]
list3 = [[111, ["book", "letters", "library", "reading"]], [112, ["education", "jobs", "companies", "salary"]]]
list4 = [[111, ["food", "curry", "spices", "rice", "fruits", "vegetables"]], [112, ["fruits", "vegetables", "farms", "farmers"]]]
list5 = [[111, ["food", "industry", "delivery"]], [112, ["fresh", "curry", "food", "pears", "passion fruit"]]]
```

I have a list of concept as well.

```
myconcepts = ["fruits", "curry"]
```

I want to find the first list that have the concepts in `myconcepts` list. i.e.

```
"fruits" -> list1
"curry" -> list4
```

I am currently using the following code to do this

```
mylists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
for concept in myconcepts:
   initial_list = ""
   counting = 1

   for mylist in mylists:
        for item in mylist:
            if concept in item[1]:
                initial_year = str(counting)
                break

        if len(initial_year) > 0:
            break
        else:
            counting = counting + 1
 print(counting)
```

This works fine for a small dataset. However, I have a huge dataset with nearly 25 lists and each list is having nearly 5 million records. My concepts list is about 15000. Therefore, my code takes lot of time to run. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: What do these numbers at index 0 mean?

Comment: 5 million records -> use pandas dataframe or numpy arrays

Comment: You could once and for all create a dictionary keyed by the concepts then querry the dictionary as needed. At some stage, you might want to use an actual data base for this.

Comment: just first list needed ? really?

Comment: i suggest first flattern all list,

Comment: ... so then you could go for a single for loop

Comment: If it's feasible, consider converting the concepts lists and the inner wordlists to [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)  Testing whether a concept set is a subset of an inner wordset should be much faster than checking that each element of the concept list is in an inner wordlist (nb converting lists to sets is expensive, so ideally you would convert once and store them - not do it every time you want to run the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an approach using `set`, which would speed up the lookup of a value using `in`, compared to lookup in a `list`.

```py
list1 = [[111, ["food", "fruits", "vegetables"]], [112, ["mango", "apples", "grapes", "pears", "passion fruit"]]]
list2 = [[110, ["transport", "car", "van", "bus", "jeep"]], [109, ["trams", "trains", "passenger", "driver"]], [108, ["traffic", "lights"]]]
list3 = [[111, ["book", "letters", "library", "reading"]], [112, ["education", "jobs", "companies", "salary"]]]
list4 = [[111, ["food", "curry", "spices", "rice", "fruits", "vegetables"]], [112, ["fruits", "vegetables", "farms", "farmers"]]]
list5 = [[111, ["food", "industry", "delivery"]], [112, ["fresh", "curry", "food", "pears", "passion fruit"]]]

myconcepts = ["fruits", "curry"]

# flatten lists and generate frozensets
flatsets = [[frozenset(l[1]) for l in lists] for lists in [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]]

# a function to retrieve indices for the strings to find
def get_idx(setlist, concept):
    for ix_f, fset in enumerate(setlist):
        for ix_s, s in enumerate(fset):
            if concept in s:
                return ix_f
    return None

# generate a list holding the index of each concept
ix_concepts = [None for _ in myconcepts]           
for ix_c, c in enumerate(myconcepts):
    ix_concepts[ix_c] = get_idx(flatsets, c)

# show result    
listnames = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'list5']    
for i, c in enumerate(myconcepts):
    print(f"concept '{c}' found first in {listnames[ix_concepts[i]]}")
# concept 'fruits' found first in list1
# concept 'curry' found first in list4
```

However, I don't think this is a 1:1 solution for the actual problem, given your vast amount of data, 15k * 25 * 5M. As already mentioned around here, a sophisticated data preparation would be required. Also, a search algorithm of O(N²) as it is now I think (neglecting time needed to flatten the lists etc.) promises to kill a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [[111, ["food", "fruits", "vegetables"]], [112, ["mango", "apples", "grapes", "pears", "passion fruit"]]]
list2 = [[110, ["transport", "car", "van", "bus", "jeep"]], [109, ["trams", "trains", "passenger", "driver"]], [108, ["traffic", "lights"]]]
list3 = [[111, ["book", "letters", "library", "reading"]], [112, ["education", "jobs", "companies", "salary"]]]
list4 = [[111, ["food", "curry", "spices", "rice", "fruits", "vegetables"]], [112, ["fruits", "vegetables", "farms", "farmers"]]]
list5 = [[111, ["food", "industry", "delivery"]], [112, ["fresh", "curry", "food", "pears", "passion fruit"]]]


def flattern(l):
    ll=list()
    for j in l:
        for k in j[1]:
            ll.append(k)
    return ll



mylists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
for j in range(len(mylists)):
    mylists[j]=flattern(mylists[j])
```

this just flatterns the list for easy searching.
then i suggest hashing and convering strings to unique no as per hash table, eg mango->0 , vegetables->1 ....

thus comparing numbers is much more efficient then comparing whole strings.